# Where to find list of standard metadata types supported?

Tags: metadata-api, metadata

Where to find list of custom metadata types to deploy/retrieve that are supported?

For example: `CustomObject`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The place to look is the [Metadata API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm), in the Metadata Types section.

Note on terminology: these are *not* Custom Metadata Types. Custom Metadata Types are a specific Metadata API entity. `CustomObject`, for example, is a built-in Metadata API entity.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the terminology correction.